# QGIS 3: Relations between 1:n

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, dialog

I have made a lot of relations (e.g. addresses).

I have a lot of tables where I use them, but if I change the address in the addresses table, then the text in all related other attribute tables will not change (instead a () will be added).

How can I have a drop-down only with the addresses from list to choose and how can it automatically change/update?

If I use the id instead of the text I only get the number displayed in property dialog of a feature.

How do I use the relation much better?

Added:

I used menu "Project" -> "Properties" -> "Relations".
Then Layer -> "Property of Layer" -> "Attribute Form" (if so called in englisch) -> Chossed Field -> Type of Element on the right site -> Relations reference.

does this help?

Is there a better place to ask QGIS-questions than here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify how you set up the "relations." Are you using the Value Relation field edit widget, or table joins, or some other method? As it stands it's too unclear for us to give you any meaningful assistance.

Comment: This is the place to ask about QGIS.  Looks like you are using this functionality: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations